# C# Foreach lines

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program for my staff team. They can contact each other between doing things, it's a chat box like skype but 1 room where they can do all that.

All i want to do is a line of code, grab a webpage (`webclient`) which is a php code for every value in a database. I want to download that but how can I do it with a foreach?
For each line (message) on that website I want to run a code `listbox1.Items.Add(message);` on a timer every 10 seconds and refresh the items with `listbox1.Items.Clear();`.

Then I add every message again, and then I'm going to only show the ones by timestamp so when they login it sets a datetime. And I will only show the messages from that time so from when they have logged in so the box doesnt get too big.

I'm not here asking for code: i have no skills in this type of c# ive never worked with c# `foreach` or advanced code of c#. I know how to download the web client, my current attempt was:

```
foreach (Line line in Webclient1); 
{ 
   //Datarow row = Client.ExecuteCommand("SELECT server_online FROM settings");
   listbox1.Items.Add(line); //foreach message in the website
}
```

but the code didn't work. I'm really bad with `foreach`, `webclient1` was a downloaded string of a website.

Comment: I'm sorry but you need to reformulate your question because this is incomprehensible.

Comment: What is `Webclient1`?  You seem to claim at the end that it's just a `string`, but the name of the variable *really* suggests otherwise.  If it's just a `string` then you've probably noticed that this loop is iterating through each character in the string.  You need to use something like `string.Split()` to turn the string into a collection of strings.

Comment: I have lost you between the third and fourth line of your question. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: This was seriously a pain to correct. At least use paragraphs and split up your sentences when you have 5 commas in them.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to use the `Line` type?  That is to do with drawing ... you probably want `string`.

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to foreach a string, you will need to make it an array first.

also your type Line does belong to the Drawing namespace and thus is not a good fit for string operations. use string instead

try:

```
foreach(string line in WebClient1.Split('\n'))
```

this will split your Webclient1 at the delimiter "linebreak" and then each line will be one element in a temporary array, that will get iterated by foreach...

in case your delimiter is different, you can also split at something else.

by the way. you can get responses by using the `WebRequest`/ `WebResponse` classes. feel free to read up on them at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/)

Comment: I imagine this would give a design-time error that you can't cast the result of `Split()` to type `Line`.

Comment: @SirCrispalot most probably ;) but hey if it's design time, i hope OP can make use of it. well i think it will be easy cuz type line is member of System.Drawing....